# Angular debounceTime: Why is not only the last value returned?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, debouncing

I have a service. This contains the following function (simplified):

```
private _eventListener$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
```

```
push(field?: FormField): void {
    this.isAlive = true;
    this._eventListener$.pipe(
      debounceTime(3500),
      takeWhile(() => this.isAlive)
      ).subscribe(() => {
        this.isAlive = false;
        console.log(field?.control.value)
      });
  }
```

This function does the following: if a field changes (input, dropdown,...) then the backend should be called and data should be queried. This should not happen directly with every change of a field but only after a certain time nothing has changed. Therefore I have thought, I use debounceTime. But unfortunately this does not work.

If I enter a lot of numbers and I am above the debounce time, all the numbers I enter are logged:

[image]

I thought debounceTime always only outputs the last value after nothing has happened for a certain time. Why does this not work?

Comment: Where is unsubscribe statement? If you subscribe, you must unsubscribe somewhere, or all subscriptions will remain active. Possibly, this is reason why subscriber is executed three times. Generally speaking, subscribing in service is really bad idea. Better approach is to return Observable stream from service and subscribe/unsubscribe in component.

Comment: Where exactly are you calling `push()` function? Is it possible that this function if called each time you type something (e.g. because it was called from your HTML during rendering)?

Comment: I think your description of the problem shows that debounceTime() itself actually works. If it didn't work it would output "1" then "12" then "123". But in your example it outputs the entire result ("123") three times. Therefore I suspect you somehow manage to make a new subscription with each keystroke (possibly because your component gets re-initialized?)

Comment: @FabianStrathaus This is called in the component when something changes: `doOnChange(event: any): void {
    this.formService.push(this.field);
  }`

Comment: @EdmundsFolkmanis I have changed my starting post. So it is not output repeatedly.

Comment: @kellermat You're right. I have changed my starting post. What could be the problem there?

Comment: Each time the key is pressed, you are subscribing to some unrelated BehaviorSubject that emits `false` immediately, then waits for 3.5s, then logs entire value of control, then unsubscribes. As you type more characters field value grows, and console output grow's. Btw, as mentioned in other answers, subscribing in that way is absolutely wrong and error prone approach. Build once observable operator`s chain in component constructor or OnInit, then subscribe once, and never forget to unsubscribe or complete on destruction. Or even beet use async pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When something is changed in your component `this.formService.push(this.field);` is called. This created a new observable (and subscription) on each change. You should just call this function one time (e.g. in your constructor) and only one value will be emitted. Please remember to unsubscribe on destruction or, even better, don't subscribe at all and use an declarative approach using `rxjs` operators + `async` pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you call `push`, you create a *new* pipeline and subscribe to it. Since the source is a `BehaviorSubject` a value is emitted immediately upon subscription, which calles the subscribe handler 3.5s later.

To be clear:
When you enter `123`, `push()` is called 3 times, you create 3 *different* and *unrelated* Observables that you subscribe to. Each of them will wait for 3.5s, then emit the value. However, since all 3 subscribe handlers reference the *same* `field`, they output all the same value.

---

You should build this observable *one* time, not on each call to `push()`. And subscribe only *once*. And in `push` you only push the next value to a `Subject`. Example:

```
private _fieldChanged$ = new Subject<FormField?>();

constructor() {
  this._fieldChanged$.pipe(
    debounceTime(3500)
  ).subscribe((field) => console.log(field?.control.value));
}

push(field?: FormField): void {
  this._fieldChanged$.next(field);
}
```